# returning boolean in nested if statement in java

Tags: java, boolean, return

Originally, I was trying to figure out how to write a method that returns a boolean. After reading the posts, I learned that apart from having a main method, I also needed a second method that can return boolean and the main method has to be void and cannot return anything. I figured out how to write another method that returns a boolean. Thanks guys!

```
public class main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = { -6, 2, 4 }; // true -6, 2, 4
    sum(a);
}

public static boolean sum(int[] a) {
    int x = 0;
    int len = a.length;
    boolean check = false;
    while (x < len) {
        if (a[x] == 0) {

            check = true;

            if (check == true)
            {System.out.println("break time yo@");
            break;}
        }
        if (a[x] + a[x + 1] + a[x + 2] == 0 ) {
            check = true;
            if (check == true)
                {break;}
        }
        x += 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Now we return check");
    System.out.println(check);
    return check;
}

}
```

Comment: You are lying :) What you describe is impossible. :D

Comment: @user26658 anyway why do you want to return boolean from main method

Comment: @Pshemo i told it's not the method we call main method starts when class run.it's valid method .it's not valid 'main' which start run

Comment: @FastSnail In that case I probably misread your comment. Sorry for confusion (removed my comment).

Comment: why am I getting so many down vote on my question? Can people give constructive feedback? I tried to make revision on my question. I am just starting to learn Java, so is it getting down vote because people think my question is too trivial?

Comment: @user26658 "why am I getting so many down vote on my question?" probably because your question is wrong "*When I have void, the code will compile*" - method can't compile with `void` return type if it contains `return something` inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main method has to have the signature `public static void main(String[] args)`  meaning you can't mark it as returning a boolean. I don't know what the point of this is but if you need it to return a boolean you should make another method to return a boolean.

Your method needs to have he signature `static boolean yourMethodName();` and fill in the method with your other stuff. Then you can call that method from main.

Comment: so inside the class, I can just make another method with signature public static void main(String[] args) and I am able to return boolean in this method?

Answer (score 0):

You have written

```
public static void main(String []args)
```

and you are returning Boolean values

```
return t;
return f;
```

it cannot accept

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to return `boolean`'s you'll need to create a method separate to you `main` method.

The `main` method signature must be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

OR

```
static public void main(String[] args)
```

but try to use the first one.

You can create you own method like so

```
public static boolean myMethod();
{
    //some code here
    return myBooleans;
}
```